# site doesn't scale properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I scale my site down or view on mobile/tablet, there is all of this margin/whitespace on right side and it cuts off text content in #main section. Why is this happening and how can I make it all scale correctly? I have tried overflow hidden on various parts which didn't solve anything and I have tried zeroing out margins and messing with padding. I'm unsure how to make it scale correctly and get rid of that extra margin/space on the right. There isnt much yet, only header, nav and #main section. 
Thank you for your help in advance

html:

```
<body>    
<header id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">.Richardson</h1>
    </div>
</header>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="my-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


<section id="main">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-8" id="welcome-text">

        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <hr class="rule">
        <p><cite>"Discipline is the bridge between goals and accomplishments" ~ Jim Rohn</cite></p>
                <p>Hey, I'm <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #FFFC31"><strong>Name!</strong></span> Congratulations on joining me in my path to becoming a highly valued, self-taught <span style="font-size: 24px; color:#FFFC31"><strong>Front-End Web Developer</strong></span>. My journey began with <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #FFFC31"><strong>Free Code Camp</strong></span> and the <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #FFFC31"><strong>Code Academy,</strong></span> as well as many youtube tutorials. I've learned <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #FFFC31"><strong>HTML, CSS and Javascript</strong></span> basics thus far. I aspire to put my coding skills to use by adding value and making a difference. Continually challenging myself and improving my craft. <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #FFFC31"><strong>I'm passionate</strong></span> about Nature, animals, traveling, serving the community, maintaining a healthy mind, body and spirit, and enjoying great food and craft beer with great people.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section> 

   <section>
       <h1>Portfolio</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint recusandae, labore, cumque voluptas consequatur excepturi aut qui delectus error harum atque fuga voluptate voluptatibus rem, perferendis laboriosam, pariatur quae hic?</p>

       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint recusandae, labore, cumque voluptas consequatur excepturi aut qui delectus error harum atque fuga voluptate voluptatibus rem, perferendis laboriosam, pariatur quae hic?</p>

       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint recusandae, labore, cumque voluptas consequatur excepturi aut qui delectus error harum atque fuga voluptate voluptatibus rem, perferendis laboriosam, pariatur quae hic?</p>
   </section>

css:
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: "Helvetica", "geneva", sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
}

a {
    color: #4e0250;
}

a:hover {

    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#main-header {
    background: #4E0250;
    color: silver;
    text-align: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#navbar {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: #4e0250;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

#navbar ul {
    padding-left: 65px;
}

#navbar ul li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 40px;
    display: inline;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar .my-nav {
    margin: 15px;
}

#main {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    background: url('../img/headon3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 757px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main .container {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 150px;

}

#main #welcome-text {
    background-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.9);
    color: #D3D3D3;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    min-width: 40%;
}

#main h1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.rule {
    border-top: 1px solid floralwhite;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is you're not letting bootstrap take care of margins padding with rows and columns properly. In order to fix this immediate issue you have two problems:

First,

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries

```
#main .container {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Is getting in the way. Let the .container class take care of itself. It uses media queries to accurately define the margin-left at different widths. What you've done here is hard code it to always be 150px, and on an iphone that is most of the screen.

Second,

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

```
Container > rows > columns.
```

You are missing a row class here:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" id="welcome-text">
```